# Cart icon dissapears on mobile and footer not showing properly on product pages

Tags: css, wordpress, woocommerce

I am helping my friend to create a WP webshop.

**First question:**
On desktop, the Cart icon loads properly in the header, on mobile it is not there. The Theme itself seems to have no option to 'enable' this for mobile.

**Site: meikuclothing.com**

I tried various CSS tricks like adding the viewport:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
```

Then I tried different CSS rules, and they work on desktop when resizing the window, but straight on mobile the Cart icon is never there:

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 768px)
.has_header_fixed_right.stick.menu_bottom .header_inner_right, .header_bottom_right_widget_holder {
  display: block;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 480px)
.has_header_fixed_right.stick.menu_bottom .header_inner_right, .header_bottom_right_widget_holder {
  display: block;
}
```

**Second question:** The footer looks good on the homepage/shop page. But when you open any product-specific page, the middle section of the footer is all wrong.

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's the solution to your 1st problem:

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 420px) {
    .shopping_cart_outer {
       display:table !important;
    }
}
```

This will show the cart icon on Mobile devices.

The solution to your 2nd problem is this CSS:

```
.tnp-widget-minimal input.tnp-submit{
    position: inherit;
}
```

I hope this will help you out.

Comment: Wow thanks a lot! I was struggling for hours to find a solution. Cheers!

Comment: I'm glad it worked for you :)